# Build Add-In for older version ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I am building ArcMap Add-Ins using ArcGIS 10.2 and I know that the AddIns won't work on lower versions of ArcGIS.

Is it possible to build the AddIn for ArcGIS 10.0 or 10.1 using ArcGIS 10.2?
I am using the "Python Add-In Wizard".

Answer (score 1):

Python AddIns were only introduced at ArcGIS Desktop 10.1, and so you will not be able to build one that works with ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Comment: How can i create a AddIn inArcGIS 10.2 targeting 10.1?

Comment: @JoséGabriel I think you should research/ask that as a new question, and edit that part out of this one.